# PHP longest increasing subsequence

Tags: php

So there are answers on here that apply to C but I am trying to do this in PHP, AND in a particular way.

I have an array of numbers like this :

> 7, 2, 6, 3, 10

I want to find the longest increasing subsequence that happens FIRST in the order given.  So for example in this case I want the result to be:

> 2, 6, 10
>
> And NOT 2, 3, 10.

What would be the best way to accomplish this ?

Comment: If I understand this: `1,2,3,6,8,10,12` should return `6,8,10,12` ?

Comment: I don't understand this, please describe the problem better and/or provide more examples.

Comment: In your example doesn't the `3` stop it from being an `increasing subsequence`? Maybe you can link to one of the threads on the C implementation you've seen?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own solution to the longest increasing subsequence coding challenge, it passed all 10 test cases.

```
<?php 

function ArrayChallenge($arr) {

  $newArr = [];
  foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $temp = array_slice($arr, $key, count($arr)-$key);
    //print_r($temp);
    $newArr[$key][] = "";
    for($i=0; $i<count($temp); $i++) {
      if ($temp[$i] > $value && max($newArr[$key]) < $temp[$i]){
        $newArr[$key][] = $temp[$i];
      }
    }
  }
  //print_r($newArr);
  $result = 0;
  foreach ($newArr as $item) {
    if (count($item) > $result) $result = count($item);
  }
  return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a solution to your question yielding the answer you expect. Basically, for every element found start a list and add items to it when they are greater than the last item in the list so far.

```
$input = array(7,2,6,3,10);
$trial = array();

echo "Input: ";
print_r($input);
echo "<br><br>\n";

foreach ($input as $key => $value)
{
  // Create a new trial for each starting point
  // ------------------------------------------
  $trial[$key][0] = $value;
  echo "Trial $key started<br>\n";

  // Process all prior trials
  // ------------------------
  for ($i = $key-1; $i >= 0; $i--)
  {
    echo "Looking at trial $i ";
    $last = count($trial[$i]) - 1;
    $lastval = $trial[$i][$last];
    if ( $value > $lastval )
    {
      $trial[$i][] = $value;
      echo "** added $value";
    }
    echo "<br>\n";
  }
  echo "<br>\n";
}

// Find first longest trial
// ------------------------
$longest = 0;
foreach ($trial as $key => $list)
{
  if ( count($list) > count($trial[$longest]) )
    $longest = $key;
}

echo "All trials:<br>\n";
print_r($trial);
echo "<br><br>\n";

echo "First longest sequence:<br>\n";
print_r($trial[$longest]);
```

There are of course things that could be done differently if you had very large data sets.  That said, here is some "debug" output showing it in action:

> ```
> Input: Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 2 [2] => 6 [3] => 3 [4] => 10 ) 
>
> Trial 0 started
>
> Trial 1 started
> ... looking at trial 0 
>
> Trial 2 started
> ... looking at trial 1 ** added 6
> ... looking at trial 0 
>
> Trial 3 started
> ... looking at trial 2 
> ... looking at trial 1 
> ... looking at trial 0 
>
> Trial 4 started
> ... looking at trial 3 ** added 10
> ... looking at trial 2 ** added 10
> ... looking at trial 1 ** added 10
> ... looking at trial 0 ** added 10
>
> All trials:
> Array ( 
>   [0] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 10 ) 
>   [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 6 [2] => 10 ) 
>   [2] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 10 ) 
>   [3] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 10 ) 
>   [4] => Array ( [0] => 10 ) 
> ) 
>
> First longest sequence:
> Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 6 [2] => 10 )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php

$data = array(7, 2, 6, 3, 10);
$slice_array=array_slice($data,array_search(min($data),$data));
$result=array();

for($i=array_search(min($slice_array),$slice_array);$i<=array_search(max($slice_array),$slice_array);$i++){
     if(end($result)<$slice_array[$i]){
         array_push($result,$slice_array[$i]);
     }
}
print_r($result);
 ?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 6 [2] => 10 )
```